# apache2 redirect http to https with full url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dnilabs.at/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So when i browse to the url http://www.dnilabs.at/loesungen/ redirects to https index.php and should be https /loesungen/

What do i miss here? shouldn't it be redirected to /loesungen/ instead of /index.php

I also tried this with the same result

```
^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Most likely other rewriting rules interfere. I suggest you enable rewrite logging, raise the log level and take a look at your rewrite log file. That allows to understand _exactly_ what is actually going on inside your rewrite engine on a step by step base.

Comment: OK it works, my problem was i placed the rules on the end of my .htaccess file, i placed it directly under RewriteEngine On and now it works

Answer (score 0):

OK it works, my problem was i placed the rules on the end of my .htaccess file, i placed it directly under RewriteEngine On and now it works